# Bootstrapping AutoMapper & StructureMap via ConstructServicesUsing

Tags: c#, automapper, structuremap, automapper-5, structuremap4

How to tell AutoMapper 5 to use StructureMap for constructing services without creating a bootstrapping problem, i.e. `new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(some_IContainer))` when the config is being made via StructureMap?

Custom resolvers need a service locator to be used by AutoMapper, but `IContainer` does not exist yet while AutoMapper is being initialised inside a StructureMap registry. The static `ObjectFactory.Container` has been deprecated in StructureMap, so I have a lazy ObjectFactory:

```
public static class ObjectFactory
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Container> _containerBuilder =
            new Lazy<Container>(defaultContainer, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get { return _containerBuilder.Value; }
    }

    private static Container defaultContainer()
    {
        return new Container(x =>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<MyRegistry>(); // AutoMapper is configured here
        });
    }
}
```

I can't reference `ObjectFactory.Container` from an AutoMapper Profile because I get a stack overflow or "Value referenced inside lazy factory".

Is there a way to tack on `.ConstructUsing(some_IContainer)` after configuring AutoMapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the container - even if it's not built yet - by using [lamdba-based registrations](http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/lambdas/).

Your registration of `MapperConfiguration` could look something like:

```cs
class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        For<MapperConfiguration>()
            .Use("Use StructureMap context to resolve AutoMapper services", ctx =>
            {
                return new MapperConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    config.ConstructServicesUsing(type => ctx.GetInstance(type));
                });
            });
    }
}
```

This way you avoid the chicken-and-egg problem.

**WARNING**

I haven't tested this code, and I'm not familiar with StructureMap.